# Is it possible to use MEF RegistrationBuilder to create a PRISM ModuleExport?

Tags: c#, prism, mef

I'm working on a sample PRISM application and I want to use the MEF `RegistrationBuilder` to create all of my exports. The equivalent of using the `ExportAttribute` is as follows:

```
[Export(typeof(IFooService))]
public class FooService : IFooService { ... }

Builder.ForTypesMatching(typeof(IFooService).IsAssignableFrom(type)).Export<IFooService>();
```

However, modules use a different attribute, the `ModuleExportAttribute`, for example:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(ModuleA), DependsOnModuleNames = new string[] { "ModuleB" })]
public sealed class ModuleA : IModule { ... }
```

I'm not sure how to use the `RegistrationBuilder` class to create the module export instead of using the `ModuleExportAttribute`. Is this even possible since it is exported differently than a standard export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `ModuleExport` attribute](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Mef.Wpf/Modularity/ModuleExportAttribute.cs) is essentially just an `Export(typeof(IModule))` atttibute with type-safe metadata (`IModuleExport`). You can easily "copy" its behavior with `RegistrationBuilder` by adding this metadata yourself. For example

```
RegistrationBuilder builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
builder.ForType<ModuleA>().Export<IModule>(eb => eb
   .AddMetadata("DependsOnModuleNames", new string[] { "ModuleB" })
   .AddMetadata("InitializationMode", InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)
   .AddMetadata("ModuleName", "ModuleA")
   .AddMetadata("ModuleType", typeof(ModuleA)));
```

You can verify this works by importing your modules like so, which is basically what Prism does behind the scenes:

```
[ImportMany]
Lazy<IModule, IModuleExport>[] Modules { get; set; }
```

You should note that you must specify in the metadata *all* the properties in the `IModuleExport` interface, or the modules will not be imported (as they don't satisfy the `IModuleExport` interface)

---

**Adding to the answer**:

**The code above is the correct, working way; the code below looks correct, but does not work.**

It's important to note that this only works if you utilize the [`PartBuilder.Export(Action<ExportBuilder> exportConfiguration)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192325(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

```
RegistrationBuilder builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
builder.ForType<ModuleA>().Export<IModule>()
   .AddMetadata("DependsOnModuleNames", new string[] { "ModuleB" })
   .AddMetadata("InitializationMode", InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)
   .AddMetadata("ModuleName", "ModuleA")
   .AddMetadata("ModuleType", typeof(ModuleA));
```

Comment: The code suggested works; It's important to note that you must use the correct `Export()` overload. Additionally, it is not necessary to add all of the Metadata, only the parts that you need, the rest will have a default value, which is okay if you don't want to specify things such as `InitializationMode` or dependencies. Thank you!

Comment: When I checked it, I wasn't able to load modules that only had the `DependsOnModuleNames` metadata so I assumed that adding all metadata is required. Maybe some properties are required and some are optional, but I'm not sure how one can know which are which.